# Relativistic Scattering

Tags: special-relativity, scattering, elementary-particles, scattering-cross-section

When we work out the relativistic general two-body scattering in the CM frame (like two elementary particles producing two other P1 +P2 -P3 -P4) , the cross section is proportional to absolute final momentum by absolute initial momentum (**Pf/Pi**). But that makes no sense to me, since for relativistic collisions the momentum, as well as the energy, is conserved.

Could anyone point to the flaw of my thought?

Comment: Yes. The cross section is proportional to **Pf/Pi**.  Tks AFT.

Comment: Could you tell us where you got that result about the cross section?

Comment: Sure, that's David Griffths, Introductuion to Elemtary Particles p.200. Exp. 6.7, eq 6.42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Halzen & Martin page 91. 
[image: electron-muon scattering]
[image: cross section formula]

Supose you're doing electron-muon scattering. **Pf** is the electron momentum in the final state, and **Pi**  electron momentum in the initial state. You are correct that the *total* momentum is conserved (it is 0 before and after, in the CM frame), but the momentum *of each particle* changes.